# The possessive 's in time expressions

Tags: grammar, expressions, apostrophe

Which is the correct answer?

> I'll be there in a _____ time.
>
> A) day or two
>   B) day or two's
>   C) day's or two's

Comment: the first one would be better.

Comment: Vaguely similar to [Three year free insurance or three years free insurance?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/327448/26083)

Comment: Just say "I'll be there in a day or two."

Comment: *I'll be there in one or two days' time.*

Comment: http://random-idea-english.blogspot.it/2014/01/a-ten-minute-walk-ten-minutes-walk.html

Answer (score 4):

B) is the correct answer.

I'll be there in a day or two's time.

https://www.google.gr/#tbm=bks&q=%22in+a+day+or+two%27s+time%22

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Check the link. It's an expression.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  It' s just an expression. None of the examples in your link use 'or'.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  There isn't a rule for every single thing.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Please put your comment back. It was a nice comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, I deleted the  three comments because I don't agree that the answer couldn't have been fleshed out. You can offer an explanation for the answer, rather than saying it's answer "B)". The link in your answer is helpful, but it doesn't explain.  I can't bring my comments back, but no real harm's been done, just delete yours, and no one is the wiser.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  My answer stands.

Answer (score 0):

I think

> I'll be there in a day or two's time.

is defensible, but it would be far more euphonious to say

> I'll be there in a day's time or two days' time.

Comment: *"A day's time or two days' time"* is much too wordy. You can say *"one or two days' time"* if you don't like the original.